# Postgresql group by multiple columns and sort within each group

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, distinct, window-functions

I have a table with the following columns:

| order_id | amount | rating | percent | customer_id | ref_id | doc_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 1 | 0.6 | 112 | 8 | 5 |
| 2 | 2000 | 2 | 0.1 | 111 | 8 | 8 |
| 2 | 3000 | 3 | 0.2 | 110 | 8 | 6 |
| 3 | 4000 | 5 | 0.1 | 100 | 7 | 7 |
| 3 | 4000 | 2 | 0.7 | 124 | 7 | 9 |
| 3 | 5000 | 4 | 0.6 | 143 | 5 | 10 |
| 4 | 2000 | 6 | 0.4 | 125 | 4 | 11 |
| 4 | 2500 | 1 | 0.55 | 185 | 4 | 12 |
| 4 | 1000 | 4 | 0.42 | 168 | 5 | 13 |
| 4 | 1200 | 8 | 0.8 | 118 | 1 | 14 |

for each order_id I want to find the doc_id having the highest amount, highest rating, highest percent, lowest customer_id.

for a single order id I can do it like this:

```
select order_id, doc_id
from orders
where order_id = 1625
order by amount desc nulls last,
         rating desc nulls last, 
         percent desc nulls last,
         customer_id asc
limit 1;
```

but I haven't been able to make it for all orders. So the output should be something like this:

| order_id | doc_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 4 | 12 |

I am using Postgresql.
Any idea how I should do this?

Comment: The data in your desired results doesn't exist in your sample data....?

Comment: it was a sample result set. I will update the result though.

Comment: Your criteria appears to conflict, why does Order_Id 3 have Doc_Id 7 when Doc_Id 10 has the higher amount?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT order_id, 
       FIRST_VALUE(doc_id) OVER (
         PARTITION BY order_id 
         ORDER BY amount DESC NULLS LAST, rating DESC NULLS LAST, percent DESC NULLS LAST, customer_id
       ) doc_id
FROM orders;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1a34706c1bb839d4e168759c91987b31).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to implement row numbering in a window, ordering by your desired criteria:

```
with t as (
select *,
    Row_Number() 
      over(partition by order_id 
        order by amount desc, rating desc, percent desc, customer_id
      ) seq
    from Yourtable
)
select order_id, doc_id
from t
where seq=1
```